# GIT: ошибка "Not a git repository"

Tags: git

Резко перестал работать GIT. Что я делаю:

Был проект. Я с ним работал давно и не трогал его совсем. И тут он мне понадобился.

1. Я выполнил команду `git status`, чтобы убедиться, что там ничего нету левого и все нормально и.... получил в лицо ошибку:

   > `fatal: Not a git repository (or any parent up to mount parent )
   >   Stopping at filesystem boundary (GIT_DISCOVERY_ACROSS_FILESYSTEM not set).`

   То же самое происходит при попытке выполнить любую команду.
2. Я не расстроился и попытался клонировать git репозиторий еще раз.
3. Вроде бы все успешно, репа клонирована, но и в ней происходит такая же ерунда.

В инете порылся, ответа, к сожалению, не нашел. Помогите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Решено.

Git хранит в себе все права на файлы и папки. По неосторожности было выполнено chmod `-R 0777 *`, после чего git решил, что это слишком большие права и теперь он не является адекватным репозиторием.